# Learning Yii2: Data Transformation

Tags: date, yii

I am busy learning Yii2, looking at this guide:
[Yii documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html)

In my customer table I have a field: customer_birthday which is of type: Date

Trying this code:

```
public function getBirthdayText()
{
    return date('d/m/Y', $this->customer_birthday);
}
```

Running my page, getting this error:
A non well formed numeric value encountered on the line:

```
return date('d/m/Y', $this->customer_birthday);
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: What's the value of `$this->customer_birthday`? PHPs `date()` only accepts a unix timestamp as integer.

Comment: Use `date('d/m/Y', strtotime($this->customer_birthday));` or `$dt = new Datetime($this->customer_birthday); return $dt->format('d/m/Y');`

Comment: Hi @inseersa.

Thank you for your reply. I changed my code to this:
In my controller I have this:
$data = `Customers::find()->where(['customer_active'=>1])->orderBy('customer_name')->all();`

In my view:
`foreach($data as $val) {
  $bday = date('d/m/Y', $val->customer_birthday);
  echo "<p>Birthday: $bday</p>";
}`

Got the error: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Tried this:
`$bday = new Datetime($cust->customer_birthday);`

Got this error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Comment: @chris, as I said, the field is of type Date. The value is: 0000-00-00
Should I change the field type to integer?

Comment: No you don't need to change the type. But you are passing a string (0000-00-00) to PHPs `date()` which needs an integer. So just convert it to use it with `date()` like `return date('d/m/Y', strtotime($this->customer_birthday));`. Make sure that `customer_birthday` contains a valid date.

Answer (score 0):

Yii 2 comes with very useful Formatter, which you can use to format your date.

Link: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#asDate()-detail

You should first properly configure formatter: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-formatting.html#configuring-formatter

And then format your dates in your needs: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-formatting.html#date-and-time

Comment: Thank you @aslawin, but I want to understand every step of this documentation I read, so I don't want to use Formatter or anything else, just what they use in the document.